# Fading in a div while animating from the left/right/top/bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make a transition where a div set to "display:none" fades in and moves to the center of the page from either the left/right/top/bottom.

How can I get it to simultaneously fade in and animate({left: })?

My current code first fades it in and then animates it.

```
$("#button" ).click(function(){
$("#text").fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $("#text" ).animate({ "left": "+=50%" }, "slow" )
    })
})
```

[Current JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny62wjes/#&togetherjs=BDroxAf3TM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the notation like in my snippet below to animate both parameters at the same time. Note: I used `opacity` for the fading animation. (And use `position: absolute` for the animated element)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#text").animate({
      left: '+=50%',
      opacity: '1'
    }, 1000);
  })
})
```

```css
#button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}

#text {
  color: deepskyblue;
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">
  Move
</div>

<div id="text">
  Hello there
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

position of the **div** with id **text** should be absolute. Here is your code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#text").fadeIn(1000, function() {
      $("#text").animate({
        "left": "+=50%"
      }, "slow")
    })
  })
})
```

```css
#button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}

#text {
  color: deepskyblue;
  fontsize: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 60px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">
  Move
</div>

<div id="text">
  Hello there
</div>
```